# How to store foreach results in a variable and use it in an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, foreach

I can't seem to figure this out. How can I store foreach results in a variable? Here is my code.

```
$ids = get_field('auction_catalog');

if($ids) {
    foreach($ids as $id => $auctionids) {
        $string .= $auctionids . ', ';
    }

    echo $string;
}
```

the result above is: `1,2,`

but the result I want to get is: `'1', '2'`

I want to use the results in an array like so...

```
array(
    'taxonomy'=> 'auction-catalog',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => array( $string ) // array('1', '2')
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently assign it to be a single string, not elements of the array. That means that you get one element in your array with the string `1, 2,`. You could `explode()` the string to convert it into elements in an array, but it's easier to just use an array from the beginning instead.

If you want the resulting array to be an array with the elements from `$auctionids`, just add them to an array that you supply to the final array, as such

```
$ids = get_field('auction_catalog');
$terms = array(); // Define the array

if($ids) {
    foreach($ids as $id => $auctionids) {
        $terms[] = $auctionids;
    }
}
```

`$term` is now an array, you can put directly in your other array, as such

```
array(
    'taxonomy'=> 'auction-catalog',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => $terms
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
$string = "1, 2";
$array = array($string);
```

will give you an array with one element with `1, 2` in it. If you want an array, build an array:

```
if($ids) {
    $idsArray = [];
    foreach($ids as $id => $auctionids) {
        $idsArray[] = $auctionids;
    }
}
```

Now `$idsArray` is an array with all your `$auctionids` as elements. Now you can use it in `terms`:

```
array(
    'taxonomy'=> 'auction-catalog',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => $idsArray
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$ids` already is an array, and all you are interested in are the values of it, you can just use `array_values()` - there's no need to loop through the array:

```
$terms = array_values($ids);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

use implode and if you want turn String to Array use explode

```
$array_to_string = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
$string_to_array= "a,b,c,d,e,f,g";

echo implode(',',$array_to_string ); // a,b,c,d,e,f,g


echo explode(',',$string_to_array); // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```